# Switching to a web framework from vanilla WSGI

Tags: python, django, flask, wsgi

Our stack split into four main components:

1. Several web applications that contain only the presentation layer
2. Another application that we called Warden that contains a set of WSGI endpoints that we define ourselves.
3. A library of classes that represent our database entities.
4. A PostgreSQL database

In order for the web applications to make requests to the database, they talk to the Warden.

We have realised that our user's needs are such that we need to write endpoints often and continually. The fact that we explicitly write our endpoints means that the turn around time from getting a request from a user to implementing is very slow.

Is it possible to rewrite our Warden in a web framework? Is there a framework that is particularly suited to this?

Alternatively, is there a different and better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to rewrite our Warden in a web framework?

The common Python web frameworks include

- Django
- Flask
- FastAPI
- Pyramid

All of these are used in large deployments that demand speed and scalability. E.g. Instagram runs on Django. There is no particular reason why your application would be more demanding than some of the largest websites in the world. Any rewrite in a web framework is possible. Whether the result is good or bad depends largely on the skill of software engineers, not the framework.